# How can I set up electron-builder.js in my project's directory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron, electron-builder

[my project's structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v3ix.png)

I am trying to make a project using electron and react.

All settings related to execution are done in package.json. The code I've written displays just fine.

However, there is a problem in the process of building my code into an application through electron-builder.

I've looked at a lot of documentation on the internet, but I couldn't find a detailed article on the many options of builder, or most of them I couldn't understand.
How can I configure electron-builder.js in the structure of my project?

The build script in package.json should do two things.
The first thing to do is to bundle my react project through webpack and save it in the build/react directory, and merge the file that I just bundled through electron-builder (I guess this bundled file is a renderer) and electron's main process.

The second thing is to save the installable file in dist directory through the process (sorry, I don't know how to express it).

Up to the stage of bundling the React project went smoothly, but I am stuck at the second stage because I could not configure electron builder correctly.

I think need to setting the appropriate options in the builder's option fields -> files field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently [wrote a blog post](https://www.debugandrelease.com/creating-a-simple-electron-application/) explaining how to create an Electron application from scratch (including using React and electron-builder). `electron-builder` requires a [number of changes](https://www.electron.build/#quick-setup-guide) in order to implement it in an Electron application. These are:

1. The name, description, version and author fields need to be populated.
2. The build field needs to be populated.
3. Icons should be added to your project (which corresponds to the build.directories.buildResources property). Sample files can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/reZach/simple-electron-template/tree/master/resources).
4. The pack, dist and postinstall scripts need to be set.
5. Remove the pre-existing directories field.

Here is a sample **package.json** you can use for reference:

```json
{
  "name": "simple-electron-template",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Electron application",
  "main": "app/electron/main.js",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "electron": "^19.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^23.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {    
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development --config ./webpack.development.js",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron .",    
    "preprod": "webpack --mode production --config ./webpack.production.js",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "MyProductName",
    "appId": "com.mycompany|electron.myproductname",
    "directories": {
        "buildResources": "resources"
    },
    "win": {
        "target": [
            "nsis",
            "msi"
        ]
    },
    "linux": {
        "target": [
            "deb",
            "rpm",
            "snap",
            "AppImage"
        ]
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

There's a [simple template](https://github.com/reZach/simple-electron-template) you can use for reference if you'd like.

Comment: OMG Your template is verrrrry appropriate for my situation!!! I posted this question and I've been studying webpack and Electron-Builder for the past week, but I haven't gotten much of an income. So thank you very much for your reply!! I will refer to your template's setting carefully and apply them to my project. Again, thank you so much!!

Comment: Thank you @dy.kim. I hope I can lead you on the right track. If you find my information is the answer you are looking for - can you consider marking my answer as accepted so that future others may know this solved your question and can lead them to their answers as well.